# How can I get the Visual Studio 2008 built-in installer to overwrite an install?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation

I want to blow away the already installed version of my app without bothering the user to uninstall before installing a new version.

Here are the Deployment Project Properties that I have set:

```
AddRemovePrograms              Icon(Icon)
Author                         Justin Tanner
Description
DetectNewerInstalledVersion    False
InstallAllUsers                True
Keywords
Localization                   English (United States)
Manufacturer                   Company Name
ManufacturerUrl                
PostBuildEvent
PreBuildEvent
ProductCode                    {3F401BEF-4A95-48AE-A79F-FBB60E90E26A}
ProductName                    Utility App
RemovePreviousVersions         True
RunPostBuildEvent              On successful build
SearchPath
Subject
SupportPhone
SupportUrl
TargetPlatform                 x86
Title                          Utility App
UpgradeCode                    {B2DC1E38-5605-4CC7-A815-2E1F9D7EDE41}
Version                        1.0
```

Comment: downvote because you didn't bother to accept the correct answer.

Comment: @qes Unfortunately I'm not working on this problem ( it's been 2 years ) and can't confirm the answer ( no visual studio ). It is upvoted that should be validation enough.

Answer (score 6):

Change the `Version` property of your installer setup project.

After making this change, visual studio will say `It is recommended that the ProductCode be changed if you change the version.  Do you want to do this?`  Choose `Yes`.

The installer created after the version and ProductCode update will automatically "upgrade" previously installed versions prior to the version update.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to configure the setup project to update the version and product code on every build to avoid having to remember to make such changes between every deployment.

Comment: This seems to work, but I still have a problem with the a windows service setup by the installer.  It doesn't remove the service, so when installing the new version it blows up trying to install a service with the same name/guid.

Comment: Managing the registration and removal of windows services as part of an installed application is a separate issue.

Comment: @ianmichael: true, although there is a significant change between the installers built by VS 2005 and later versions that is directly related.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/bedbb8bd-dad5-4bcb-a87a-ac69386669b4/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just run the uninstall operation then select your installer project and go to properties and then set RemovePreviousVersion = True...

Comment: Good idea!, tried that but still get the "Another version of this product is installed. Installation cannot continue...."